# how would I convert this interface block into a command

Tags: linux, command-line, ifconfig

I tried this:

```
ifconfig br0 192.168.0.1 broadcast 192.168.0.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 network 192.168.0.0 gateway 192.168.0.1 up
```

But it did not work I am trying to use all of these parameters:

```
address 192.168.0.1
broadcast 192.168.0.255
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

How Would I achieve converting all of my interface parameters to a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own result:

```
ifconfig br0 192.168.0.1 broadcast 192.168.0.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `network 192.168.0.0` is superfluous; it's derivable from address and netmask. I'm not sure where you got it from, but it's not something `ifconfig` is happy with.

Try `man ifconfig` for more details.

Comment: same with the broadcast address - it is useless